# Fetching data from product custom option

Tags: magento2, additional-options

Hi i am trying to get data from **quote_item_option** table but am not able to get it

below is my code :- .................

```
<?php

$orderid = 4;
 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface')->load($orderid);
 
//Loop through each item and fetch data
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $item->getOrderID();
    $arr = $item->getProductOptions();
    $json1 = json_encode($arr);
    echo($json1);

    $customOption1 = $arr->getSubscriptionType();
    $json2 = json_encode($customOption1);
    echo $json2;


    $customOption2 = $arr->getStartDate();
    $json3 = json_encode($customOption2);
    echo $json3;
}
?>
```

also am getting the data here  `$arr = $item->getProductOptions();`

```
{"info_buyRequest":{"uenc":"aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo5Ni9tMjQyL3B1Yi9zcHJpdGUteW9nYS1zdHJhcC04LWZvb3QuaHRtbA,,","product":"2","selected_configurable_option":"","related_product":"","item":"2","qty":"1","ntz":{"Subscription Type":"Monthly Plan","Start Date":"06\/17\/2021"}},"additional_options":[{"label":"Subscription Type","value":"Monthly Plan"},{"label":"Start Date","value":"06\/17\/2021"}]}
```

**I dont prefer to use object manager this is just for own testing.**

Please let me know what am missing.thanks

Answer (score 0):

**try to use:**

```
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
{
 $options = $item->getProductOptions();
 $optionName= $options['option_name'];
}
```

Comment: tried but am getting this Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: subscription_type

Comment: i have used option_name as demo, you can use like color,size etc if your product have these options.

Comment: i have already tried that but getting the same error

Comment: use print_r($options) to check.

Comment: as i hvae already mention in my question that am getting the value here $item->getProductOptions();

Comment: can you please share the ss of where you have created this custom option "subscription_type"

Comment: i have added those option in phtml file and then called it on the pdp page

Comment: kindly share the steps you have followed to create the options.